How do I fix this jgrasp format where everything is in a separate window
I accidentally turned on a setting of some kind, and my JGrasp which was one window composed into roughly 3 parts (java file, browse at the left, and system (compile messages, jgrasp messages, etc) at the bottom), split into multiple windows. Picture below. Picture
How do I turn it back into just one window?
(I tried to look around the view and window tab of the settings but didn't find the problem. Also tried googling it but couldn't find this problem or answers.)

"Settings" > "Desktop" > "Virtual Desktop"
